Finding available objects in a command to parse to where-object
My apologies if this has been asked elsewhere. I cannot find any answer and am beginning to suspect I am looking at this incorrectly.
I have been using PowerShell for some years, but have not really for to grips with it properly, so I am now trying.
When I look at the following command(s);
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.WorkingSet -gt 100-MB}
I understand the command and that is is getting the Where-Object command to examine the WorkingSet object and return any process using greater than 100MB, in this case. What I was finding difficult was getting a list of the objects that the Where-Object command can process/sort though.
I now know these are coming from the Get-Process command by typing 'Get-Process | Get-Member', so I try this on a different command - Get-MSOLCompanyInformation and the Get-Member command lists all the Properties and Methods, so I try to use the Where-Object command to extract something useful;
Get-MsolCompanyInformation | Where-Object postalcode
This did not need a comparison operator and returned the address, phone number and other stuff. Brilliant.
Then I thought lets try other properties. Of the ones I can get to return something successfully, like 'street', 'LastDirSyncTime', 'AllowAdHocSubscriptions', they all return the same. The ones that don't return anything is what is bugging me. If there is a property, I should be able to extract it and get Where-Object to return it.
I have tried;
Get-MsolCompanyInformation | where-object -property dapenabled -eq true
Get-MsolCompanyInformation | where-object -property dapenabled
Get-MsolCompanyInformation | where-object -property dapenabled -eq false
None of these return anything, but don't give an error, so why can I not get output from ANY property of ANY command?
I think there is something I am not getting. Anyone got any idea what I'm talking about?

First, try to use $true and $false. Second: what is the type of DapEnabled? Forcing comparison to a boolean could easily fail, especially if it's $null: $null does not equal $false in Where-Object. Check the result returned by comparing to $null

You can readu up on MSolCompanyInformation here.  In the sample shown, there is no property named DAPenabled.  Is this also true in your situation?

It's a strange property of powershell that if you name something that does not exist, it will often invent such an object, and give it a null value.  This can make it hard to trace wrong spellings.

The official docs here do list DapEnabled as property of the output. Perhaps different versions?

@WalterMitty: The list of display properties is generally not a reliable indicator of the full set of properties defined on an output object, because only a subset is often chosen (via formatting files). For reliable discovery, use Get-Member -Type Properties
